# Группировка записей таблицы MYSql по датам laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Здравствуйте в LARAVEL необходимо группировать записи таблицы по дате создания (группировать по дням, месяцам, годам) которая записывается в формате TIMESTAMP. Не подскажите можно ли это сделать запросом SQL и возможно в LARAVEL есть специальные методы для этого?

Comment: Вот примеры любых запросов с laraverl https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для группировки результата запроса по метки времени, можно использоваться стандартный метод построителя запросов Laravel - `GroupBy`

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$lists = Foo::orderBy('created_at') // Сортируем по метки времени
  ->get() // Выполняем запрос
  ->groupBy(function($lists) {
     return Carbon::parse($lists->created_at)->format('m'); // Сгруппировать результат запроса по месяцу
     });
dd($lists);
```